# What does the double slash mean in `${f// /_}`?

Tags: bash

I'm learning Bash, and I want to replace space characters with other "non blank" characters. I'm using a `for` loop:

```bsh
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

My question is, why are the double slash and the space in `${f// /_}`? What does `${f// /_}` do?

Comment: If you don't need to learn it by heart, you should at least know where to read about it: it's in [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thats a replacement pattern using `bash` parameter expansion.

In `${f// /_}`:

- The double slashes `//` are for replacing all occurrences of space with `_`, if you put one slash `/`, only first space is going to be replaced
- The space is there because you are replacing space (with underscore)

So the pattern basically is:

```
${parameter//find/replace}
```

Check `man bash` to get more idea.

To get to the `Parameter Expansion` section of `man bash` at once:

```
LESS=+/'Parameter Expansion' man bash
```

Comment: In short, its a **global** search and replace.

Answer (score 4):

The section `"{f// /_}` means replace every space with and underscore.
This is using Bash parameter expansion, the variable `f` defined in the `for f in *\ *;` will be run through for every match of shell expansion (globbing). Each time the filename found will become the value `$f`.

The parameter expansion works with the `//` meaning every occurrence of the character following `//` (space in this example), should be replaced by the character after `/` (underscore in this example).